# Meaning of "Honours" in the Leverhulme Trust fund application

Tags: funding

I am applying for Leverhulme Trust Research Project Grant. In one of the sections, the application system has this field called "Honours" that we need to fill in. I am not sure what it is? Does it mean highest education qualification obtained?

Any ideas?

Comment: It probably refers to awards or prizes you may have been given over the course of your career, but if you're still uncertain it would be best to get in touch with Leverhulme and ask.

Comment: I think I will do that. I need to ask them a few queries anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer. It probably refers to awards or prizes you may have been given over the course of your career, but if you're still uncertain it would be best to get in touch with Leverhulme and ask.